# Google sheets data validation issue

Tags: google-sheets

I need to data validate a column so that it only allow:
A-Å, a-å, 0-9, Comma, dot, ?, !, -, +, (, ), :, <, >

I use this custom formula:
=REGEXMATCH(A1:1,"[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]")

But I cannot get the dialog box to save the formula?
and how do I get my regex to match my allowed characters?

Only if I exclude the = from the formula field but then the data validate does not work...

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_MeBbhL1nR1rF1JYGI2cpd88VAhqKJCgN25KS6STfWU/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=REGEXMATCH(A1&""; "[a-zA-Z0-9\sÅå,\.\!\?\-\+\(\)\:<>]")
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your formula is correct but you just needs to correct the cell reference.

```
=REGEXMATCH(A1,"[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]")
```

[Sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hLtoGtFuBsEJzTeF9-wgL0JhygXrtcqrrbGeGc-85uQ/edit#gid=0)